# Drop down list select using python selenium (xpath)

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

```
  &nbsp;Month 
<select name="filterMonth" onchange="document.form.submit()">
<option value="0"></option>
  <option value="01">January</option>
  <option value="02">February</option>
  <option value="03">March</option>
  <option value="04">April</option>
  <option value="05">May</option>
  <option value="06">June</option>
  <option value="07">July</option>
  <option value="08">August</option>
  <option value="09">September</option>
  <option value="10">October</option>
  <option value="11">November</option>
  <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```

How can I select drop down list for `"filterMonth"` using xpath?

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/select[2]')
```

gives me error that no such element found

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xpath

```
//select[@name='filterMonth']
```

if name is unique across the page.

```
Select select =new Select(driver.findelement(By.xpath("//select[@name='filterMonth']")));
select.selectByVisibleText("January");
```

This for Java. please change it accordingly for python.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons why you get `NoSuchElementException` might be using `tbody` tag in your `XPath` as this tag not always present in initial `HTML` source, but might be generated dynamically. The other reason is that entire `table` could be generated dynamically and you should wait a little to be able to handle it:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

select = wait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "filterMonth")))
Select(select).select_by_visible_text("March")
```

Also you can use provided by @Murthi `//select[@name="filterMonth"]` XPath to select drop-down

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code:

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='filterMonth']"))

# select by visible text
select.select_by_visible_text('January')
```